# JPA query LIKE does not work

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

What is wrong with this query: `SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE 1 = 1  AND UPPER(i.nome) LIKE %:nome%  ORDER BY UPPER(i.nome)`? I tried with and without single quotes in LIKE '%:nome%' but it doesn't work.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE 1 = 1  AND UPPER(i.nome) LIKE %:nome%  ORDER BY UPPER(i.nome)]. 
[56, 63] The identification variable '%:nome%' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
```

Comment: Use `like :nome`, and prepend/append the percent signs to the parameter value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/425742), you need to wrap the value with `%` while setting the parameters, e.g.:

```
query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE 1 = 1  AND UPPER(i.nome) LIKE :nome  ORDER BY UPPER(i.nome)");
query.setParameter("nome","%"+nome.toUpperCase()+"%");
```

Comment: % is needed in different positions because of the search in my application. There are 3 options to search: substring, whole word and alphabetical/start of string.

Comment: The link you posted is not to the JPA documentation. It points to the spring-data-jpa documentation, that the OP is most probably not using. If he was using it, the query he uses would work fine, as the documentation you linked to says: it would transform this invalid JPQL query into a valid one.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your inputs. I have updated the answer.